# ImageView adjustViewBounds not working

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I have an ImageView with `android:layout_width=100dp`, `android:layout_height=wrap_content` and `android:adjustViewBounds=true`

It's source is  a 50 x 50 px picture. But the aspect ratio is not preserved - height of the ImageView is 50px, not 100px (i.e. `adjustViewBounds` is not working). If I have a 200x200px picture it works - width and height are 100px. This code results in a 100px wide and 50px tall picture but the src image is square:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That normally works; can you provide an exact code snippet? Also what's the ImageView's parent? Perhaps its parent is forcing a certain size, not allowing the ImageView to resize.

Comment: Ah I found the issue, will provide an answer now.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The issue is that `adjustViewBounds` *will not increase the size* of the `ImageView` beyond the natural dimensions of the drawable. It will only shrink the view to maintain aspect ratio; if you provide a 500x500 image instead of a 50x50 image, this should work.

If you're interested in the spot where this behavior is implemented, see [ImageView.java's onMeasure implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java).

One workaround is to implement a custom `ImageView` that changes this behavior in `onMeasure`.

Comment: do you know of any library that fixes this behavior of the imageView?

Comment: I have now created a version of ImageView which also scales up *and* scales down if you have match_parent/fill_parent, which the original ImageView neither does. In effect, I find this version of ImageView to be much more practical when doing aspect-ratio scaling in a dynamic layout. Feel free to copy. Source: https://gist.github.com/Nilzor/5402789

Comment: A ScalingImageView which works as if adjustViewBounds=true and always changes the height based on the width and drawable intrinsic aspect ratio: https://github.com/triposo/barone/blob/master/src/com/triposo/barone/ScalingImageView.java

Comment: This behaviour seems to have changed with Android 4.3. My views now increase beyond their natural size. Can you confirm that @RomanNurik?

Comment: @aleb Thanks works fine! devisnik - It doesn't increase size of a image on my S5 with 4.4.2 and Galaxy Nexus 4.3. Maybe it's device specific.

Comment: @devisnik, u'r right. That method now can scale the dimension up beyond the image size

Answer (score 13):

There's a more simple way. Make your ImageView like this:

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:scaleType="fitCenter"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

This way **drawable will stretch to fit in the ImageView center** by preserving
the aspect ratio. We just have to calculate the right height to make it proportional
so we don't have any blank space:

```
private void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, ImageView imageView){
    float i = ((float)imageWidth)/((float)bitmap.getWidth());
    float imageHeight = i * (bitmap.getHeight());
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(imageWidth, (int) imageHeight));
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: This only a good solution if align the image in the center of the view is what you want. If you need to have a flexible alignment, see Roman Nuriks answer and my comment there.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @RomanNurik's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719617/imageview-adjustviewbounds-not-working/7732684#7732684)

You can find working solution [here](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/correct-imageview-adjustviewbounds-with-adjustable-imageview/en), either copy-paste code or just add the Gradle dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.inthecheesefactory.thecheeselibrary:adjustable-imageview:1.0.1'
}
```

P.S. Solution provided by @Nilzor didn't work for me

Comment: For next readers, the view is called `com.inthecheesefactory.thecheeselibrary.widget.AdjustableImageView`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement; in my case, I wanted the image to be square, and wanted the ImageView to match the aspect ratio so I could use its background and padding to draw a border.

I read the answers here but instead of overriding ImageView, I decided to make a Layout that guarantees its contents (should be only one view) are square. That way I could use a standard ImageView inside it. (And you never know, I might want to make something else square later. Although probably not.)

In case it's useful for anyone else, here's the code (feel free to copy). There are probably bugs as I just made it work for my app then stopped. :)

```
public class SquareLayout extends ViewGroup
{
    public SquareLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public SquareLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareLayout(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        // Work out width and height, and square size.
        int width = r - l;
        int height = b - t;

        int size, xOffset, yOffset;
        if(width < height)
        {
            size = width;
            xOffset = 0;
            yOffset = (height - size) / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            size = height;
            xOffset = (width - size) / 2;
            yOffset = 0;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            child.layout(xOffset, yOffset, size + xOffset, size + yOffset);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        // Get width and height.
        int w = -1, h = -1;
        switch(MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec))
        {
        case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            break;

        case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
            break;
        }
        switch(MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec))
        {
        case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            h = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            break;

        case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
            break;
        }

        // If only one of width/height is unspecified, set them both the same.
        if(w == -1 && h != -1)
        {
            w = h;
        }
        else if(h == -1 && w != -1)
        {
            h = w;
        }

        // Either they're both specified or both unspecified.
        int childMeasureSpec;
        if(w == -1)
        {
            childMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        }
        else
        {
            childMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(w, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        }

        // Pass through to children.
        int maxDimension = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            child.measure(childMeasureSpec, childMeasureSpec);
            maxDimension = Math.max(maxDimension, child.getMeasuredWidth());
            maxDimension = Math.max(maxDimension, child.getMeasuredHeight());
        }

        if(w == -1)
        {
            w = maxDimension;
            h = maxDimension;
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this line will do it for you android:scaleType="fitXY"