# android adjustViewBounds bug?

Tags: android, imageview

When I use android:adjustViewBounds="true" in my imageView xml, it does not function. If I put setAdjustViewBounds(true); in the constructors of my ImageView, it works fine. What is the difference, or is this a bug?

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/PageViewMainImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="matrix"     
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"               
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Comment: See this SO Thread it may help you


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719617/imageview-adjustviewbounds-not-working

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The order of operations in the `ImageView` constructor ([see source here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java)) parses out and sets the `adjustViewBounds` property from XML before it parses and sets the `scaleType` attribute from XML.  Part of the `setAdjustViewBounds()` method (which is called by the constructor with your XML attribute value) is to set the `ScaleType` to `FIT_CENTER` when the value is true.

So when the XML you posted is loaded, the `ScaleType` is first set to `FIT_CENTER` and then re-set to `MATRIX` afterwards, all inside the constructor.  Compare this with your example of calling `setAdjustViewBounds()` in Java instead, and now the final `ScaleType` will be `FIT_CENTER` as your Java call will happen after the XML attributes are parsed (effectively meaning that your `android:scaleType="matrix"` attribute is ignored.  That difference is likely what you are seeing between "works" and "doesn't work".

I'm not sure if Google would call it a bug, as they are only setting the `ScaleType` to what they think you want as a convenience to preserve the aspect, but still allow you to modify this.  The bounds of the view themselves will still change as the property name directs, the image just may clip in a way you didn't expect.

The docs could probably be more clear on this "feature" though, so you could file a bug report at http://b.android.com

HTH

Comment: AdjustViewBounds won't scale up past the natural size of the bmp.  If your bmp is 50x50 that is the most you can get out of it, you won't get a scaled image in a 200x200 window.  To fix this you need to provide a bmp larger then the window so it can scale down.