# Expandable list view with image as view group header

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have an expandable list view. The view group header is an image Here is the code for this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
 />

</LinearLayout>
```

When i set targetSdkVersion to 20, the image get shrink and there is white space on all four side of images, on phones with API level <20. The reverse happens when i put targetSdkVersion to 17. i.e phone with API level >17 suffers from same issue. Any help would be appreciated.!

Comment: If the application targets API level 17 or lower, adjustViewBounds will allow the drawable to shrink the view bounds, but not grow to fill available measured space in all cases. This is for compatibility with legacy MeasureSpec and RelativeLayout behavior.

Comment: I want to target API level >16.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917388/android-adjustviewbounds-bug check with this answer.hope its helpfull

Comment: I tried setadjustviewbounds(true) in code but it didnt help.

Comment: try with  set the ScaleType to FIT_CENTER

Comment: It didnt help. I tried CenterCrop but it is clipping image from top and bottom but it fills entire parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with reference to following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680499/how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-an-android-widget-imageview)

```
int finalHeight, finalWidth;
final ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.scaled_image);
final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.size_label);
ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
public boolean onPreDraw() {
    iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
    finalHeight = iv.getMeasuredHeight();
    finalWidth = iv.getMeasuredWidth();
    tv.setText("Height: " + finalHeight + " Width: " + finalWidth);
    return true;
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**List Group.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#821418" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"  >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />



</LinearLayout>
```

**Main Acitivity.java**

```
 //Deifine the all variable for the expandable platform **//
     ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
     ExpandableListView expListView;
     List<String> listDataHeader;
     HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

  // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

     // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

     // Listview Group click listener
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

     // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });


     // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }
        });


     // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)+ " : "+
                listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
 }
        });
```

**ExpandableListAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.lcofieldmanagement;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
 // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;


    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context,List<String> listDataHeader,HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData){
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

            txtListChild.setText(childText);
            return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is simple one.i suppose the question was about adding image to it.