# top align image over ImageButton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am trying to set the image at top over ImageButton as follows

[image]

But I am not being able to do so. if  I use following code

```
<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"

>
    <ImageButton

         android:id="@+id/btn"
         android:layout_width="40dip"
         android:layout_height="40dip"
         android:src="@drawable/button_bar_top"
         android:scaleType="fitStart"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

And I am getting following look

[image]

So I want to align it to the top and I want to remove extra padding around red bar. The size of the image is 40 X 10 and width of ImageView is also same

Comment: Does the drawable button_bar_top have padding or something? Is it an image or xml file?

Comment: i have both and image and a shape too , image doesn't have any padding

Comment: try `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` instead of `fitStart`... And check whether original size of ur image is not smaller than the ImageButton size...

Comment: @GAMA fitCenter will come into the horizontal center so tht doesnt work

Comment: @Hunt : check whether original size of ur image is not smaller than the ImageButton size as sometimes `android:adjustViewBounds="true"
` doesn't show the desired effect... refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719617/imageview-adjustviewbounds-not-working

Comment: @Gama ImageButton automatically reduces the size of image which is inside the ImageButton , so bigger dimension doesnt work too

Comment: Have you tried larger dimension image... Bcoz ur imageButton width is 40 **dip** and ur image width is 40 **px**... and ***dip=px*** is generally false.... px = dp * (dpi / 160)....

Comment: Hey i tried that with 50 px and i said if the image is large then ImageButton is auto scaling it and reduced its size

Comment: i tried with 62px and ImageButton with 40dip but no luck

Answer (score 1):

It seems you could use `Button` here with `android:drawableTop` attribute that will do exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Zelleriation we do have drawablePadding to tackle with that issue.

Comment: The padding is in the buttons default background drawable so setting drawablePadding wont´t help, unless you change the buttons background drawable..

Comment: yeah we have to set the background to white or something

Answer (score 0):

**try this it wil solve the problem**

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgbtnNew"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10sp"
            android:onClick="onNew"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: cant understand why to set Image src for both ImageView and ImageButton , i thing ur trying to vertically align ImageView over ImageButton but this wont overlap and to overlap i got to assign negative margins and have to use FrameLayout. so i tried it but doesn't help