# Add an image in the middle of button?

Tags: android, xml, layout

So I have created a button in my layout, but I wanted it to be a circle.
So I created an .xml drawable like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#673ab7"/>
    <stroke android:width="2sp" android:color="#fff" />
</shape>
```

Then in the button bit in the layout i added this

```
android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
```

But now I wish to have an image inside the circler button. How can I achieve this? Can I simply add something in the drawable xml?

I've tried searching for answers but I am confused to what I should search for.

Comment: see my answer and give me feedback to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtn"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
        android:src="@drawable/image_to_insert"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to change circle_button to src and then I made background my image. seemed to work fine.

Comment: Glad, you found the solution.

Comment: this solution has defects read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719617/imageview-adjustviewbounds-not-working.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you go for relativelayout. Just take relative layout having circle shaped image to its background. Only the thing is you need circle shaped image.

For example,

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/circle">  //circular shaped image circle.png
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Finally you just have to apply listener to your layout. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Explain me how it takes an image in middle. Read the question once again and edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create a RelativeLayout instead of button and put your image inside the layout and set its attribute `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to true;

so it will be in the middle of the RelativeLayout. And set the `android:background="@drawable/circle_button"` to the RelativeLayout. Now get the RelativeLayout using it id and add a click listener to RelativeLayout

Comment: If correct answer is already present, then you don't need add same answer. You can just upvote to that answer. This is how stackoverflow works.

Comment: first of all take a name user3811114 . the given answer is not as correct as mine. And in stackoverflow you can submit multiple answer. so that you can find multiple approaches to get the work done.