# Android ImageView, adjustViewBounds not working in Android 4.1

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

In my implementation `adjustViewBounds=true` works exactly as expected in android 5.1
but doesn't do the same in 4.1

> 4.1 on left, 5.1 on right

```
adjustViewBounds=true
```

[image]

```
adjustViewBounds=false
```

[image]

**`MainFragment`**

```
<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="150dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    tools:context=".MainFragment"
    android:id="@+id/movie_gridView">
</GridView>
```

**`ImageView`**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/gridView_moviePoster"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719617/imageview-adjustviewbounds-not-working

Answer (score 0):

> If the application targets **API level 17 or lower**, `adjustViewBounds` will allow the drawable to shrink the view bounds, but not grow to fill available measured space in all cases. This is for compatibility with legacy MeasureSpec and RelativeLayout behavior.

so On Api level 17 and less you have to use an AdjustableImageView

Add below in gradle

```
compile 'com.inthecheesefactory.thecheeselibrary:adjustable-imageview:1.0.0'
```

For detail tutorial [**See this**](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/correct-imageview-adjustviewbounds-with-adjustable-imageview/en)